# How can I use customvalidator to validate 2 inputs, clientside

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, webforms

I try to use a asp:CustomValidator together with clientside javascript in order to check so that the user does not enter the same new password as the old password like this..

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function CustomValidator1_ServerValidate1(source, arguments) {
        var sOldPassword = document.form1.<%= tbOldPassword.ClientID %>.value;
        var sNewPassword = document.form1.<%= tbNewPassword.ClientID %>.value;
        if (sOldPassword == sNewPassword) {
            arguments.IsValid = false;
        } else {
            arguments.IsValid = true;
        }
    }
</script>

<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
                     ErrorMessage="Old and new password cannot be the same"

                     ClientValidationFunction="CustomValidator1_ClientValidate1"
                     ValidateEmptyText="True" ValidationGroup="Custom"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

but it does not work, anyone see why it does not work?

Comment: Function name passed is wrong. ClientValidationFunction="CustomValidator1_ClientValidate1" it should ClientValidationFunction="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate1" as per your js

Comment: Sorry that did not help. If I enter the same value in the 2 textboxes it still let me submit the form...

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue, I should have used document.getElementById in the javascript instead.